# Find the following limits or prove they don't exist

Tags: complex-analysis

$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\bar z} z$

I think that the limit is 1 but i'm not sure how to show that

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{z^*}{z}$?  And if so, what does $z^*$ mean?

Comment: Do you mean $\lim\limits_{z\to 0} \frac{\overline{z}} z ?$ If so, try writing $z$ in exponential form.

Comment: z* is meant to be the conjugate of z but i didn't know how to get that on the keyboard so yes i meant what stefan has put

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by exponential for, do you mean x-iy/x+iy

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\bar z} z$ does not exist: approaching zero on the real axis gives you a limit $1$ and approaching on the imaginary axis gives $-1$.

Comment: would just stating this constitute as a proof?

Comment: It would certainly be safer to give some details. One possibility is to use the definition of limit directly. Another way is to construct two sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ such that $x_n,y_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ but $\overline{x_n}/x_n\to 1$ and $\overline{y_n}/y_n\to -1$.